# How do we denote the $0$ vector in a Quotient Space $V /W$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, notation, quotient-spaces

Just $0$ or $0 + W$? Unfortunately my textbook has no mention of the notation for this, nor can I find clarification for this online.

Comment: In the quotient space $V/W$, the elements are of the form $v+W$ for $v\in V$. The zero element is given by $0+W$ or simply just $W$ or $0$. It is convenient to use either of them, depending on the situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the most standard way to write it is just $0$, but you can also call it $0 + W$ or $[0]$. There is no fixed notation in this sense: Different books use different notations.